# Numeric (not integer or double precision) picture token Clarion+Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, clarion

i need numeric mask like this:

```
100
101.1
102.123
```

Take maksimum given decimal places but if last digit is 0 trim it.
Something like:
@n-12_`2 but trim right 0 and .
Ex:

```
x = 102.1230057::double precision
select rtrim(rtrim(round(x::numeric, 2)::text, '0'), '.')::numeric
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need right aligned numbers, you can use `@S10` (or the length you want).

Comment: But @s10 order values : 1 101 2 201 not numeric 1 2 101 201

Answer (score 0):

@P<#.##P style pictures might help.